# Use Math.NET's Fit.Polynomial method on functions of multiple parameters

Tags: c#, curve-fitting, math.net

I previously used Math.NET Numerics library's [Fit.Polynomial](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Fit.htm) method to fit a cubic polynomial on a set of data that could be modeled as a function of one parameter `y=f(x)`.
Now I would like to similarly find a 2 or 3 order polynomial that fits data that could be modeled as a function depending on multiple parameters `y=f(x1, x2, x3, x4)`.

Is there already a built-in function in Math.NET that can compute that polynomial?
If not, do you see how I could manipulate my data in order to submit it to Fit.Polynomial?

Comment: What would your f look like exactly in case of, say, 2 variables and order 2?

Comment: To keep it simple, I would say something like: `f(x1, x2) = a*x1*x1 + b*x1 + c*x2*x2 + d*x2 + e`

Comment: Maybe I can use the [Fit.MultiDim](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Fit.cs) method with an approach similar to what you describe in your [post about linear regression](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/linear-regression-mathnet-numerics.html): using `x1*x1` and `x2*x2` as separate parameters. However I am afraid this will produce results less accurate than using Fit.Polynomial (it was the case when I tried to do Cubic Function Fitting using your trick to leverage Linear Regression). Do you see any better method?

Answer (score 14):

The `Fit` class is just a facade that is good enough in most scenarios, but you can always use the algorithms directly to get exactly what you need.

`Fit.Polynomial:` Polynomial curve fitting with high orders is a bit problematic numerically, so specialized algorithms and routines to tune/refine parameters at the end have been developed. However, Math.NET Numerics just uses a QR decomposition for now (although it is planned to replace the implementation at some point):

```
public static double[] Polynomial(double[] x, double[] y, int order)
{
    var design = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(x.Length, order + 1, (i, j) => Math.Pow(x[i], j));
    return MultipleRegression.QR(design, Vector<double>.Build.Dense(y)).ToArray();
}
```

`Fit.MultiDim` on the other hand uses normal equations by default, which is much faster but less numerically robust than the QR decomposition. That's why you've seen reduced accuracy with this method.

```
public static double[] MultiDim(double[][] x, double[] y)
{
    return MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(x, y);
}
```

In your case I'd try to use the `MultipleRegression` class directly, with either `QR` (if good enough) or `Svd` (if even more robustness is needed; much slower (consider to use native provider if too slow)):

```
var x1 = new double[] { ... };
var x2 = new double[] { ... };
var y = new double[] { ... };

var design = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRowArrays(
    Generate.Map2(x1,x2,(x1, x2) => new double[] { x1*x1, x1, x2*x2, x2, 1d }));
double[] p = MultipleRegression.QR(design, Vector<double>.Build.Dense(y)).ToArray();
```

(Using Math.NET Numerics v3.0.0-alpha7)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will try them asap.

Comment: I managed to get results using MultipleRegression.QR, but I want more precision (no problem if the process is slow). I tried to use MultipleRegression.Svd instead, but I block on an exception on line 2212 of [this file](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Providers/LinearAlgebra/ManagedLinearAlgebraProvider.Double.cs) (revision [857751979..](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/commit/857751979bf1a1948ac7ad9ab3d74f19fbc12daf)). Are you aware of a revision where this problem does not happen?

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: The error is `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. It appears that the size of array `double[] u` passed is 0. It seems to be created [here](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/857751979bf1a1948ac7ad9ab3d74f19fbc12daf/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Double/Factorization/DenseSvd.cs#L64), but is not set afterwards, and passed [two lines later](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/857751979bf1a1948ac7ad9ab3d74f19fbc12daf/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Double/Factorization/DenseSvd.cs#L66) to `Control.LinearAlgebraProvider.SingularValueDecomposition` via `u.Values`.

Answer (score 5):

[RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#C.23) proposes this solution for polynomial regression(using [Math.Net](http://www.mathdotnet.com/)):

```
    public static double[] Polyfit(double[] x, double[] y, int degree)
    {
        // Vandermonde matrix
        var v = new DenseMatrix(x.Length, degree + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < v.RowCount; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= degree; j++) v[i, j] = Math.Pow(x[i], j);
        var yv = new DenseVector(y).ToColumnMatrix();
        QR<double> qr = v.QR();
        // Math.Net doesn't have an "economy" QR, so:
        // cut R short to square upper triangle, then recompute Q
        var r = qr.R.SubMatrix(0, degree + 1, 0, degree + 1);
        var q = v.Multiply(r.Inverse());
        var p = r.Inverse().Multiply(q.TransposeThisAndMultiply(yv));
        return p.Column(0).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: This code requires a small update, initialize the QR like this: QR<double> qr = v.QR();. Now it supports Generic Types. Also updated in RossetaCode

Comment: flip QR<double> qr = v.QR(); to var qr = v.QR(); this does away with a using statement :D

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the ***x*** in the linear model can also be a vector ***x=[x1 x2 ⋯ xk]*** and the arbitrary functions ***fi(x)*** can accept vectors instead of scalars.
[Here](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/regression.html#Multiple-Regression) is something nearly about what you want.